# Derivative of $f(x) = \tan(x)-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Can you help me to find first and second derivatives of the following function: $$f(x) = \tan(x)-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also use latex to write up math please, it makes it much more readable.

Comment: Start by asking yourself: "What is the most important (central) operation in the expression?" Then: "What formula applies to this operation?" Then you'll have 2 expressions to derive and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

by the quotient and the power rule we get $$\left(\tan(x)-(x-1)^{2/3}\right)'=\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}-\frac{2}{3}(x-1)^{-1/3}$$